# The Actor DSL example from Akka doc

Tags: scala, akka

I try to implement Actor DSL example from akk doc, but found error,

**ambiguous implicit values: both method senderFromInbox in trait Inbox of type (implicit inbox: 
 akka.actor.ActorDSL.Inbox)akka.actor.ActorRef and value self in trait Actor of type => 
 akka.actor.ActorRef match expected type akka.actor.ActorRef**

below is my code,

```
import akka.actor.ActorDSL._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent.duration._
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("demo")

implicit val i = inbox()
val a = actor(new Act {
  become {
    case "hello" ⇒ sender ! "hi"
  }
})
a ! "hello"
val reply = i.receive()
```

here I can't use "!" to send message, only can use "tell" like **sender.tell("hi", null)**, does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer (only for REPL without `:paste` mode):

```
val a = ...
implicit val i = inbox()
```

You should pass `self`, not `null` as second parameter (`sender`) of `tell` method. Method `!` takes this parameter implicitly and invokes `tell`. There are 2 implicit `ActorRef` in scope of `sender ! "hi"`: `i` and `self` (field of `Act`) - compiler can't figure out which one you need.

You should remove `implicit val i` from scope of `sender ! "hi"`.

Correct solution - move actor creation to method and all other code - to other method. In REPL you could create `a` before `i`.

Quick dirty solution - hide `i` like this:

```
val a = {
  val i = 0
  actor(new Act {
  ...
}
```

Comment: correct. For this test code, I just want to test the DSL function, so not put self to tell method, yes it should be put