# What is the reason this type parameter syntax doesn't compile?

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-2.10

Say I have:

```
class Class[CC[A, B]]
class Thing[A, B <: Int]
class Test extends Class[Thing] // compile error here
```

I get the compiler error:

> kinds of the type arguments (cspsolver.Thing) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type CC) in class Class. cspsolver.
>   Thing's type parameters do not match type CC's expected parameters: type C's bounds <: Int are stricter than type B's declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any

However when I modify the code such that it looks like this:

```
class Class[CC[A, B]]
class Thing[A, B] {
  type B <: Int
}
class Test extends Class[Thing]
```

it compiles fine. Aren't they both functionally equivalent?

Comment: In the last example you have type parameter `B` and type member `B`. They have the same name (so only one is visible), bot they are not the same.

Comment: @senia, is there a case where using the same name is useful?

Comment: @huynhjl: I guess no. But in some cases shadowing is useful: you can reuse name. There are also some partial useful abuses of shadowing in case of implicits: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17852226/406435).

Comment: @senia You should turn your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted. You have the right answer and it's simple.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: thank you, but it's not an answer. I've explained why last code sample compiles, but not why the first one doesn't compiles.

Comment: @senia Oh, you're right!

Comment: @senia Darn, you're right. I thought it did some sort of label replacement. I thought I solved my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason is given in the compiler message. In `Class` you expect an unrestricted `CC`, while `Thing` has the restriction that the second type argument must be `<: Int`. One possibility is to add the same constraint to `Class` as in

```
class Class[CC[A,B <: Int]]
class Thing[A, B <: Int]
class Test extends Class[Thing]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why this restriction is in-place; why can't the compiler reconcile the two at the lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Petr Pudlák's explanation, here is what I **assume** happens: The compiler tries to unify `CC[A, B]` with `Thing[A, B <: Int]`. According to the declaration of `B` in `CC`, `B`'s upper type-bound is `Any`, which is picked to instantiate `B`. The `B` in  `Thing`, however, is expected to have `Int` a its upper type-bound, and the compiler thus fails with the error message you got.

This is necessary in order to preserve soundness of the type system, as illustrated in the following sketch. Assume that `Thing` defines an operation that relies on the fact that its `B <: Int`, e.g.,

```
class Thing[A, B <: Int] {
  def f(b: B) = 2 * b
}
```

If you declared `Class` as

```
class Class[CC[A,B]] {
  val c: CC
}
```

and `Test` as

```
class Test extends Class[Thing] {
  val t: Thing
}
```

without the compiler complaining, then you could make the following call

```
new Test().t.f(true)
```

which is obviously not safe.

Comment: I'm not convinced you have a valid example of why "allowing such a type constraint to compile" would fail.. but since it wouldn't even compile it's hard for me to pin down exactly why it's wrong!

Comment: But I'll try anyway: `def f(b:B)...` is in the context of `B <: Int`. So I'm not buying that in any circumstances `f(true)` could possibly compile.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why `new Test().t.f(true)` wouldn't be caught at compile time. In `Test` wouldn't `t`'s type need type parameters? And if it did wouldn't `new Test().t` return `Thing[A, B <: Int]`, so that the compiler would know `new Test().t.f` takes a `B <: Int` and that `Boolean` is not `<: Int`?

Comment: @RichardSitze @eddiemundorapundo My line of thought is the following: If the compiler picked `Any, Any` as the missing arguments to `Thing` in `... extends Class[Thing]` because `A,B` in `Class[CC[A,B]]` have no explicit upper bounds and if the compiler didn't raise an error, then effectively `val t: Thing[Any, Any]` and hence `f(b: Any)`. `Test().t.f(true)` would thus be ok. Of course, since it doesn't compile and we (at least, I) don't have formal Scala typing rules at hand, it is hard to say whether it would actually work this way.